# VB6 and SQL mistake

Tags: sql, syntax, vb6

Here is a line of code in SQL I am attempting to use in VB6.

```
Dim Sqlstring As String

Sqlstring = "Update TroubleTickets set ResolvedDate = ' " + DateValue(Now) + "' where      Title ='" + Trim(TicketComboBox.Text) + "'"
```

I am getting an error that says types do not match when i run the debugger.

any suggestions?

Comment: You can [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587754/vb6-sql-database-error), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036637/jframe-and-jpanel-problems) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972684/creating-a-jframe-to-display-a-checkerboard).

Comment: Awesome.  Stack Overflow will love you now, and I retract my original complaint. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim Sqlstring As String

Sqlstring = "Update TroubleTickets set ResolvedDate = ' " & DateValue(Now) & "' where      Title ='" & Trim(TicketComboBox.Text) & "'"
```

The concat-operator in VB is the ampersand `&`.
You get a type mismatch error because VB expects a number if you use `+`.

You should also consider using [prepared statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905910%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to insert parameters into SQL queries.

Comment: And your DB should be using correctly taped fields for dates whihc means you need to pass the data in the exact literal format that the database expects (i.e #12/31/2011 12:34:56#) rather than a string literal (i.e ' blah')